# i cant use node in nvm except for system node

Tags: node.js, npm, raspberry-pi, nvm

I have a problem with using my node in nvm

I can see my node when i enter `nvm ls`

```
        v9.11.2
       v14.16.1
        v16.0.0
     ->  system
```

Then, I enter `nvm use 14`, which prints out `Now using node v14.16.1 (npm v6.14.12)`

however, when i enter `node -v`

it prints out `-bash: /home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/bin/node: No such file or directory`

then, when i enter `nvm ls`, i cant find an arrow that points my current node.(arrow just dissapear)

```
        v9.11.2
       v14.16.1
        v16.0.0
         system
```

this problem occurs except for system node

Also, i can find that node file if i manually go into that directory.
How can i solve this problem?

I am currently using rpi4 with rasberry pi OS(aarch64).

+) i have to enter `nvm use system` every time i reboot my computer

Comment: What are the results of `ls -l /home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/bin/node`?

Comment: its `-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi 72420328 Apr  7 00:11 /home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/bin/node`

Comment: Hmmm....how about `command -v node`?

Comment: it prints `/home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/bin/node ` However, I get `-bash: /home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/bin/node: No such file or directory` when I enter 'node'

Comment: How about if you enter `/home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/bin/node -v` as your command? Does that print v14.6.1 or tell you file not found?

Also, you're not doing `sudo`, are you? What's the result of `whoami`?

Comment: `-bash: /home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/bin/node: No such file or directory` and whoami result was`pi`

Comment: Do you have `ldd` installed? What's the output of `ldd /home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/bin/node`?

Comment: It says `not a dynamic executable`

Comment: I can't believe it's taken me this long to think of it, but what version of `nvm` are you using? (Type `nvm -v`.) If it's anything less than 0.38.0, try upgrading. Also, what does `npm root -g` say?

Comment: Looks like you're not the only person experiencing this: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/2458

Comment: I am currently using nvm `0.38.0`, however, I found out that I was using `6.14.12` version of npm. so I upgraded npm to `7.11.1` and `npm root -g`  printed `/usr/lib/node_modules`. (Unfortunatly, upgrade of npm didn't made any change)

Comment: What happens with `sudo /home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/bin/node -v`?

Comment: it says `sudo: unable to execute /home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/bin/node: No such file or directory` sudo even can't detect it

Comment: Your home directory isn't NFS mounted, is it? Does `sudo ls /home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/bin/node` work?

Comment: I just had a very similar issue on Alpine and I'm wondering if the problem is that `nvm` has installed an incompatible binary. Are you on a Pi 0 or Pi 3 or what?

Comment: yes, `ls` does work printing `/home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/bin/node`. Also im using raspberrypi 4

Comment: Pi 4 would be an ARMv8 processor but the ARM binaries built and distributed by Node.js are built and tested on ARMv7 (Pi 2 and Pi 3). I wonder if that's the issue. I'm going to leave a comment in the about GitHub nvm issue and ping the person who does all the hands-on Pi stuff for Node.js.

Comment: Can you chime in on https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/2458 or else in another comment here with the output of `uname -a`? (I assume you're still having this problem.)

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I don't have a github account. Would you add a comment for me? The result of `uname -a` is `Linux raspberrypi 5.10.17-v8+ #1403 SMP PREEMPT Mon Feb 22 11:37:54 GMT 2021 aarch64 GNU/Linux`.

Comment: Done! https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/2458#issuecomment-836908706

Comment: Here's a response in the GitHub issue that you may be able to provide some information on: Maybe someone using a native arm64 Raspberry Pi OS could manually download, unpack and try to run node from the arm64 tarball @ https://nodejs.org/download/release/latest-fermium/ and report back whether that works or not. Perhaps we have an interesting binary incompatibility for arm64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone experiencing this found a workaround and posted it to a GitHub issue about this problem.

*Originally posted by @Ratstail91 in https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/2458#issuecomment-854910734*:

I don't have a real solution - but I think I found the cause. Run the following command on your raspberry pi 4:

```
uname -m
```

If this shows `aarch64` or similar, then nvm also thinks that the raspberry pi is 64 bit, and tries to download the 64 bit version of node. Node's 32-bit build still works just fine, but for some reason the 64 bit build is failing in this very unusual way.

My only real answer is to download "Linux Binary - ARMv7" from here:

https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/

and place it in the system path. It's inelegant, but it should work, in thoery.

Comment: Yes! It worked!
`$pi@raspberrypi:versions/node ‹3fea549›$ node -v
v16.3.0`
I never thought I could manage this problem. You gave me a very big help. 
Thank you!